# Unable to get the joined table's Id wise name in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, join

In my code, I have two tables 1.`cv_products` 2.`cv_category`.

`cv_produucts` fields are -> `id`,`title`,`body`,`image`,`category`,`slug`. 
`cv_category` fields are -> `id`,`name`.

I want when I enter the details page it gives me an error that the `name` is undefined though I've joined these tables.

I'm able to fetch the data in listing page there is no problem of fetching `name` of category from `cv_category` table by the `cv_products`.`category`.

model:

```
class Product_model extends CI_Model{
    public function __Construct(){
        $this->load->database();
    }


    public function get_products($slug = FALSE){
        if($slug === FALSE){
            $this->db->order_by('cv_products.id', 'DESC');
            $this->db->join('cv_category','cv_category.id = cv_products.category', 'left');
            $query= $this->db->get('cv_products');
            return $query->result_array();

        }

        $query= $this->db->get_where('cv_products', array('slug' => $slug));
        return $query->row_array();
      }
    }
```

Controller

```
    public function index(){

           $data['subview']= 'pages/listing';
           $data['cv_products'] = $this->Product_model->get_products();

           $this->load->view('layout_main',$data);
           print_r($data['cv_products']);
    }


public function view($slug= NULL){
      $data['post'] = $this->Product_model->get_products($slug);


        if(empty($data['post'])){
            show_404();
        }
      $this->load->view('pages/product_view',$data);  
}

public function get_categories(){


    $this->db->order_by('name');
    $query = $this->db->get('cv_category');
    return $query->result_array();

}
```

view:

```
  <div class="col-5"> 
        <p><?php echo $post['title'] ?></p>
        <p><?php echo $post['body'] ?></p> 
        <p><?php echo $post['name'] ?></p>
   </div>
```

Comment: you have to add columns you want to get from your query, you have joined both tables but you should set selected columns too. 
`$this->db->select('cv_produucts.title, cv_produucts.id, cv_produucts.body, cv_category.name');`

Comment: look at the listing page in can fetch the cv_category name by foreach loop.But when click the product's slug link then details page comes, there I can fetch every field of cv_products but unable to get the cv_ctegory name.

The core php code is `SELECT * FROM cv_category WHERE name= cv_products.id`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When $slug has value, you missed to join the category table. Try like :

```
public function get_products($slug = FALSE){
    if($slug === FALSE){
       ...
    }

    $this->db->join('cv_category','cv_category.id = cv_products.category', 'left');
    $query= $this->db->get_where('cv_products', array('slug' => $slug));
    return $query->row_array();
  }
}
```

Comment: How can say thanks to you,, I've not been able to solve it from last three days and by typing one line you just solved my problem. So much thanks and good wishes to you.Thank you

Answer (score 0):

the name of category is actually not selected in your query, its true that you've joined both tables, but you have to **select** columns you want from them too.

```
  public function get_products($slug = FALSE){
            $this->db->select('cv_produucts.title, cv_produucts.id, cv_produucts.body, cv_category.name');
            $this->db->join('cv_category','cv_category.id = cv_products.category', 'left');
            if(!empty($slug)){
              $this->db->where('cv_products.slug',$slug);
            }
            $this->db->order_by('cv_products.id', 'DESC');
            $query= $this->db->get('cv_products');

            return $query->result_array();
      }
    }
```

Comment: thank you man, Somehow I've learned something from your code but what I was looking for is not that code but I learned from your code.And my problem was I didn't join the table in slug time.Look I've accepted that answer. But thank you so much

Comment: your welcome, glad to hear that your problem solved .